# File Associations for Web Sites

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I think I read once that google chrome was working on some kind of API for mapping file extensions to web sites, so that you could for example have a .docx map to a url like http://word.com?OpenFile=%1  Opening the file from your OS would fire up the browser and take you to the appropriate site and give the site access to the file.

Is this true or am I just going crazy?  If so, where can I find the spec for that system?

Comment: Although I found the answer useful (and upvoted it), this question should really be on superuser.com.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "computer enthusiasts and power users" and everything to do with web development.  This is the right place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Found it at http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/06/working-with-chromes-file-browser.html and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/fileBrowserHandler.html

**Take that, close voters!**

Comment: and you can enjoy my post as well: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/how-to-use-the-new-chromebook-file-api/